# Changing the default behavior of the mobile button "Go Back". React Native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-stack

I have a BottomTabsNavigator with two buttons: home and menu, the screen for menu shows a list of items that are clickable, it allows the user to navigate to another screen (say ShowDishes) that is not in the BottomTabsNavigator (because I made it invisible)

This other screen is also a list of clickable elements that allow the user to navigate to another screen (say ShowDish).

The problem is that if the user presses the default mobile phone button “go back”, it will navigate to home, and not to the previous screen that it was on

I’m using navigation.navigate:

```
navigation.navigate("Other Screen", {
    someProperty: { someValue},
});
```

With this navigation I can pass arguments (*and this is one reason I made some buttons invisible, since these screens need some arguments to operate, from the bottom tab menu button I don't have the values, but from the items themselves I do have the values given by the FlatList (index)*)

So the user can navigate to the ShowDishes screen, then it can navigate to the ShowDish screen, but if the user presses the default android button of “Go Back”, **how can I lead the user to the ShowDishes screen?** (if the user was in ShowDish), but it goes to Home instead (there are only two buttons, Menu and Home in the BottomTabsNavigator, I imagine it is the reason why)

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

The main idea is: two buttons tabs: home and ShowCategories.

ShowCategories show a list of categories, each category is a list of dishes,  no special navigation yet

But when the user presses a category it navigates to ShowDishes, which is a list of dishes, then pressing one of them, it navigates to ShowDish (navigation ends here)

```
           <MainTab.Navigator
                initialRouteName="ShowCategories"
                screenOptions={{
                    tabBarActiveTintColor: "white",
                    tabBarInactiveTintColor: "black",
                    tabBarStyle: {
                        backgroundColor: "gray",
                    },
                }}
            >
                <MainTab.Screen
                    name="Home"
                    options={({ route }) => ({
                        headerShown: false,
                    })}
                    component={Home}
                />
                <MainTab.Screen
                    name="ShowCategories"
                    options={({ route }) => ({
                        headerShown: false,
                    })}
                    component={ShowCategories}
                />
                <MainTab.Screen
                    name="ShowDishes"
                    component={ShowDishes}
                    options={({ route }) => ({
                        headerShown: false,
                        tabBarButton: () => null,
                        tabBarVisible: false, //hide tab bar on this screen
                    })}
                />
                <MainTab.Screen
                    name="ShowDish"
                    component={ShowDish}
                    options={({ route }) => ({
                        headerShown: false,
                        tabBarButton: () => null,
                        tabBarVisible: false, //hide tab bar on this screen
                    })}
                />
            </MainTab.Navigator>
```

And the navigations. In order to go to ShowDishes:

```
<Pressable
    onPress={() => {
        navigation.navigate("ShowDishes", {
            categoryIndex: { itemIndex },
        });
    }} ...
```

In order to go to ShowDish:

```
<Pressable
    onPress={() => {
        let propsForShowDish = {
            categoryIndex: { categoryIndex },
            itemIndex: { itemIndex },
        };

        navigation.navigate("ShowDish", {
            propsForShowDish: propsForShowDish,
        });
    }} ...
```

I works good. But, if the app is in ShowDish, going back should mean to go back to ShowDishes, but instead, it gos to home, which is the other button in ButtonTabs

Comment: please paste your navigation setup

Comment: done. I pasted the important parts of the navigation